# How can I edit the slugs of tags?

Tags: tags, slug

I'm interested in specifying different URL slugs for tags than the text they contain (e.g. changing the slug for a "QnA" tag to "questions-and-answers"). What's the easiest way of making and maintaining these changes for a large number of tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dashboard -> Posts -> Post Tags**

Click Tag (or click "Edit" in the hover quick-menu) to edit the tag's details, including slug.